# структура react проекта

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components

Если у вас есть проекты на react, особенно если там ещё присутствует typescript и styled components, попрошу скинуть сюда ссылки.

У меня проблемы с составлением структуры проекта. Я читал много статей по этому поводу но все они дают только базовое понимание как структурировать проекты. Хотелось бы увидеть примеры на практике.

Большое спасибо!

Comment: Как удобно, так и структурировать.

Comment: Читайте повторно вопрос пожалуйста если непонятно о чем я пишу

Comment: На самом деле вам и это не поможет :) Потому что каждый структурирует как ему кажется удобнее и правильнее. На тему структурирования есть 100500 статей и в каждом, кроме того что статику выносят в другой файл, всё по разному. Очень многое зависит от цели проекта, от интсрументов и т.д. Я сам просто в одно время пытался в этом разбираться и ни к чему однозначному не пришёл. Это как спросить а как построить правильный `MVC`, да просто никак, как удобнее так и делают. Главное чтобы он был расширяем хотябы в рамках существующих задач

Comment: Но именно в рамках React + TS, я обычно делаю папки: `Pages`, `Components`, `Redux`, `Types`, `Router`. Ну и понятно что в каждом 100500 подпапок и файлов

Comment: Я не фронтендер, но мои приятели оттуда хвалят данную методологию: https://feature-sliced.design/